# Rails - json column vs seperate table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on a Ruby on Rails project in which I have objects with association to instructions, meaning, each object, can have zero or more instruction objects that hold some basic data, like title, data (string), and position (for ordering them in the UI). I tried looking up an answer in google but found no relevant answer. the instructions are specific to each object and shouldn't be used for lookup or search of any kind, and therefore I figured I should store them as JSON within the object's own table instead of making a join table. The reason I think of doing so is that join table would explode when there would be many objects and because of that querying for each object's instructions would get longer over time. Is that a reasonable concern for storing this data as a JSON instead of has_many association?

Comment: Methinks this is a prime example of [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 1):

Think of using JSON in an RDBMS as a form of denormalization. There are legitimate reasons to use denormalization, but you must keep in mind that it always optimizes for one type of query at the expense of other types of queries.

For example, in this case you could query your object and it would include the JSON document containing all instructions. But if you wanted to search for a specific instruction, it would be quite complex to search for the row that has a JSON documenting containing a specific instruction. Have you thought about how you would query that?

Using normalized database design, i.e. the join table you mention, allows for more flexibility in queries. You can query the object table, or you can query the instruction table. Either way, then simply join to the other table to the the corresponding rows.

The way to make this more optimized is to use indexes on the columns you want to search. See my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Using JSON creates a lot of complexity that you probably haven't considered. See my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong).

Comment: Another Rails specific argument is that by using a JSON column you forgo all the advantages of associations and having a model to represent the data and you instead end up writing a bunch of garbage code to deal with "primitive" data types like arrays or hashes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! Would definitely check out those articles. So let's say I have multiple instructions, and a user decides to change their order (position), wouldn't it affect performance updating those N rows?

Comment: Updates benefit from indexes too. If you have the right indexes, updates only need to examine the relevant rows, and this is quick.